# Twitter API invalid or expired token

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, twitter, restsharp

I'm trying to use the below code but for some reason I'm getting an invalid or expired token it seemed to work once but never again.

Any ideas? (consumerKey and consumerSecret are constants generated in the class.)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string twitterAccount = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccount"];
        JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        var model = new TwitterVM.LandingModel();

        var qs = GetToken();
        string oauthToken = qs["oauth_token"];
        string oauthTokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];

        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com/1.1")
        {
            Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(consumerKey, consumerSecret, oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret)
        };
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("statuses/user_timeline", Method.GET);

        request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter()
        {
            Name = "screen_name",
            Value = twitterAccount,
            Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost
        });

        request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter()
        {
            Name = "count",
            Value = 10,
            Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost
        });

        request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter()
        {
            Name = "include_rts",
            Value = true,
            Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost
        });

        request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter()
        {
            Name = "include_entities",
            Value = true,
            Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost
        });

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        model.Tweets =
          jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<List<TwitterVM.Tweet>>(response);

        return View(model);
    }


    private NameValueCollection GetToken()
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com") { Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret) };
        //Do the auth shit...
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("oauth/request_token", Method.POST);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response.Content);
    }
```

Comment: I use *oauth2* api with *HttpClient* (no RestSharp).. I can post a sample code if you are interested..

Comment: Yes please if you could that would be awesome

Comment: OK.. I posted as an answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Twitter's OAuth2 API (*https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token*)

See https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only for details....

```
var client = await CreateHttpClient("....", "....");
//don't dispose this client and use for subsequent API calls

var screenName = "....";
var count = 10;
var include_rts = true;
var url = $"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={screenName}&include_rts={include_rts}&count={count}";

var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

---

```
public static async Task<HttpClient> CreateHttpClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
{
    var bearerToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(consumerKey + ":" + consumerSecret));
    string url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic " + bearerToken);

    var resp = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).ConfigureAwait(false);
    resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var jObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(result);

    if (jObj["token_type"] != "bearer") throw new Exception("Invalid Response From Twitter/OAuth");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + jObj["access_token"]);
    return client;
}
```

Comment: My application is locking up at this line `var resp = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));`

Comment: @Zhorian I tested it before posting... It may be a deadlock case (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Can you test it in clean app?

Comment: @Zhorian BTW: I updated the code with `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: Yeah I had to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` in a couple of other places and it worked! Now I just need to find out why the deserializer isn't returning the tweet entities.